# Is there a function in PHP that's equivalent to Arrays.asList(val) in Java?

Tags: php

I have an array in PHP defined as:

```
$myArray = array(
    "key_1"  => "value_1",
    "key_2"=> value_2",
    "key_3"=> value_1",
)
```

Is there a function that could print it as:

```
[{key_1=value_1, key_2=value_2, key_3=value_3}] ?
```

I know Java provides Arrays.asList(myHashMap) for doing this for hashmaps (which are associative arrays like PHP)

Is there a function in PHP that's equivalent to Arrays.asList(val) in Java?

Comment: This is not really a Java question since you're not looking for a Java solution to your problem. The tag was confusing, bringing the wrong experts to the question, and so I've removed it.

Comment: Do you need that exact output format for interoperability with another system, or do you just need to serialize data for later use within PHP?

Comment: Yes. I need that output format for interoperability with another system. I could hardcode the brackets and the curly brackets. I currently have a nasty foreach loop, but I was wondering if there was something out of the box.

Comment: Nope. That's not a format I've ever seen in PHP-land. If its got a proper name you might be find a lib on [packagist](https://packagist.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any array method that does this.

One way:

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key=$value ";
}
```

Another one (`each` is deprecated as of php 7.2):

```
print_r(each($myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty way you could achieve this is with the following

```
$array = array(
    "key_1" => "value_1",
    "key_2" => "value_2",
    "key_3" => "value_1",
);

echo str_replace('"', '', str_replace(':', '=', json_encode([$array])));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the content of an array with the keys, you can use the `print_r($array)` or `$return = print_r($array,1)`, to have the string assigned to $return variable.